# SQL Server: what to do when a decimal isn't really a decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, varchar

I have a situation where a decimal figure isn't truly a decimal, it is a sub-count of sorts. For example, when an prescription for medication is filled it is given an Rx number (lets say 345673).  That number will stay with the prescription throughout any refills and the refills append a .1, .2 etc. So, over the life of that Rx number you could end up with 345673, 345673.1, 345673.2... ongoing. The problem is when you hit .10, .20, .30 etc. In decimal form those records are the same as .1, .2, .3.

Is there any way to track these numbers and support the trailing zeros without having use `VARCHAR` etc? This is the primary key column and I'm not crazy about using `varchar` on a Pk (is that old fashioned?)

Any and all suggestions/help is appreciated.

**Edit to add:** I should have explained why we can't use separate columns for this. This data originates elsewhere and is merged into our database from a bulk import operation. The merge is perpetual since much of the data is altered at the origin and combined on the next bulk import. The Rx number has to match exactly to perform the bulk import / merge.

Comment: Use varchar, or use 2 columns with a combined key.  I'm not a big fan of combining different data elements in the same column.  One is a Rx Number, the other is refills.  seems like two data elements to me.  However if you must, Varchar as a PK is fine.  Just don't expect to do math on the field, or if you must do math always do it though a common function so it's easy to adjust later.  Not sure if MSFT version you're on supports Function based indexes but those may meet your need as well (in conjunction with computed columns)

Comment: I should have explained why we can't use separate columns for this.  This data originates elsewhere and is merged into our database from a bulk import operation.  The merge is perpetual since much of the data is altered at the origin and combined on the next bulk import.  The Rx number has to match exactly to perform the bulk import /  merge.  I'll add this to the question.

Comment: Does it have to be the primary key? You could have a simple ``id int identity(1,1) not null`` as the PK and a unique non-clustered index on the Rx Number but that change might be more than what you are asking for.

Comment: @jgiven  Then I'm back to using a Varchar.  The real answer is to understand how the data's coming to you.  If they treat it as varchar, you should as well. The question on how they process when refills get to 10 or 20 is simply to handle it within a function.  If and only if you have to do math on it.  Otherwise it's display only data and why bother?   Why fight what the industry has already figured out.

Comment: Do you ever perform maths on these numbers? I'd have thought it extremely unlikely, in much the same way that you're unlikely to perform maths on telephone numbers. And for much the same reason, I'd recommend `varchar` - they *are* strings that just happen to consist of a sequence of digits. You shouldn't be treating them as numbers.

Comment: No math on the Rx number itself, Damien.  Maybe I need to get past my aversion to using strings as PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `composite primary key`.  Add a second column, perhaps called `refill`, and use that for your incremental values.  That way both columns would be integers and no need to use varchar for your primary key.

You may need to use a `trigger` to maintain the value as `identity` fields don't work with groupings.

Comment: Thanks... the column is not identiy, just PK. Since it originates elsewhere, we have no control over the combination of the Rx + Refill.  That combination is also standard practice in the industry.

Comment: After going around in circles a bit, I think I am going to give this a shot in combination with a computed column.  Never really considered composite primary key before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the decimal to `varchar` using either `CONVERT` or `CAST`.  Then you can use character/string functions such as `LEFT()`, `SUBSTRING()`, and `REPLACE()`.

The other option is to parse out the decimal using math:

```
DECLARE @RxValue decimal(18,4) = 100.234
SELECT @RxValue [Rx Number]
    ,@RxValue - CONVERT(int,@RxValue) [Refill Count Decimal]
    ,LEN(CONVERT(float,(@RxValue - CONVERT(int,@RxValue))))-2 [After Decimal Length]
    ,POWER(10, LEN(@RxValue - CONVERT(int,@RxValue))-2) [Calc multiplier for Refill Count]
    ,CONVERT(int,@RxValue) [Rx ID]
    ,CONVERT(int,(@RxValue - CONVERT(int,@RxValue)) * POWER(10, LEN(CONVERT(float,(@RxValue - CONVERT(int,@RxValue))))-2)) [Refill Count]
```

The last two columns in the above select are your two desired columns.  All that is above is my attempt to "show my work" so you can see what I was thinking.  The "-2" is to to remove the "0." out of the `LEN()` function's result.  The `POWER()` function takes the 10 and raises it to the power of the decimal result.

You should only need to replace all references to `@RxValue` with the column name of your "Rx number" to make it work.  If you want to play around with it, you can change the values in `@RxValue` to whatever you want and make sure the result is what you expect.  **Be sure you change `@RxValue`'s data type to match yours.**

You can, of course keep your "Rx number" as the PK if that is the situation it is in.  You'll just be adding a couple of derived columns: `[Rx ID]` and `[Refill Count]`.

Please leave a comment if you have a question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation coge.soft.  I don't think this will be something I use in this exact situation, but the opportunity to learn from this has given me some ideas about how to handle some other upcoming tricky issues.